# Python-Boto: Check the Array Position Availability

Tags: python, arrays, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, boto

I have try to get a specific list of AMI and store it in the array list.

```
usubuntuamilist = {}
for i, image in enumerate(conn.get_all_images()):
    if image.location.startswith("ubuntu-images-us/ubuntu-lucid-10.04-i386-serve"):
        print "%s - %s" % (i, image.name)
        usubuntuamilist[i] = image.name
```

How can check if the array position have an existing AMI?

I check using this way but it does not work

```
userinput = raw_input("Select: ")

try:
    usubuntuamilist = usubuntuamilist[userinput]
    print usubuntuamilist.location
except:
    print "Does not exist!"
```

Alternative I also tried checking using this way. Both ways does not work

```
if usubuntuamilist[input] is not None:
    print usubuntuamilist[input]
else:
    print "Does not exist"
```

Any ideas? If there is a better alternative to solve this, I would like to heard it!

Comment: What happens when the array element does not exist? If an exception is thrown, your first option should work. If the element retrieved is `None`, the second option should work. If something else is happening, can you describe that situation?

Comment: Unfortunately, the second options also didn't work.

Comment: Something else happening?  @MichaelMior

Comment: Let say if there is a AMI in position '11', I will push it to the array that I have declare 'usubuntuamilist[i] = image.name'. But when doing the checking it just didn't works

Comment: What happens on the line `usubuntuamilist[i] = image.name` when `usubuntuamilist[i]` does not exist?

Comment: Let say position '11' have a value, position '12' does not have a value and position '13' have a value.


`code
usubuntuamilist[11] = "Something 11"

usubuntuamilist[12] = # The if statement will not reach this command #

usubuntuamilist[13] = "Something 13"`

@MichaelMior

Answer (score 1):

Why not just:

```
if image.location.startswith("ubuntu-images-us/ubuntu-lucid-10.04-i386-serve"):
        # As before...
else:
        usubuntuamilist[i] = None
```

Then, checking is the image name is None is simple, no?